# size of /root and /home partition

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, root, home

I'm using linux for the first time.
I will not use it as my primary os till i get the hang of it.
So i have made my /root: 14GB, swap: 6GB, /home: 9.5 GB.
Is my set up enough for experimental usage?

Comment: Hard to say ... If you're going to download 3 sizable movies home will be full. If you're only going to do python development it may work like this forever.  That said: swap is rather large, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have heard that swap partition should be double the size of ram or 1.5 times is ok, i have 4gb ram. So i have made the swap partition 6 GB

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Linux mint, I'd suggest you this:

Your root `/` partition will have almost all the binaries, configs, and almost everything that your systems **needs** to live. I usually spend 50GB on my root partition just to be sure that I'll have all the space that I could possibly need.

Your swap partition usually (not always) needs to be at least the same as your RAM, I have 12Gb from RAM, I have a 10Gb swap partition, this way I'm almost secure that if I suspend my laptop the ram will go to my swap partition and no information will be lost.

The last part, `/home` is where all your personal info is going to be, this means all your files, photos, movies, etc... I use 700Gb for that, and currently, I have almost 200Gb of free space... so you will need a big `/home` if you want to have it as your primary os.

Hope this will help you to make an idea of how to make your partition.

PS. just if you want to know... I have 3 distros, one Gentoo, one Arch and one Kali, Kali and Arch are both a single root (`/`) partition from almost 50Gb, and the Gentoo is 50Gb from root and the rest goes to `/home` and the three share the same swap partition